# ANSIBLE: Loop on environment variables

Tags: loops, ansible

I want to play a shell module in Ansible with multiple environment variable.
I want so to loop on a list registered in my vars. The playbook looks like this :

```
vars:  
  tcd_environment_variable:  
    - { abc_variable: "MSG" , abc_value: "HelloWorld" }  
    - { abc_variable: "REP_USER" , abc_value: "/home/user" }  

tasks:  
  - name: "Test command with environment variables registered"  
    shell: "echo $MSG >> $REP_USER/test_env.log"  
    environment:   
      "{{ item.abc_variable }}": "{{ item.abc_value }}"  
    loop: "{{ abc_environment_variable }}"  
    become: yes  
    become_user: user
```

I can't make it work, only this works :

```
tasks:  
  - name: "Test command with environment variables registered"  
    shell: "echo $MSG >> $REP_USER/test_env.log"  
    environment: 
      REP_USER: /home/user
      MSG: "HelloWorld"
    become: yes  
    become_user: user
```

But I want to loop on Ansible variable.
Thank's for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [*items2dict*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-lists-into-dictionaries) to transform the list to a dictionary, e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    abc_environment_variable:
      - {abc_variable: "MSG", abc_value: "HelloWorld"}
      - {abc_variable: "REP_USER", abc_value: "/tmp"}
  tasks:
    - name: "Test command with environment variables registered"
      shell: "echo $MSG >> $REP_USER/test_env.log"
      environment: "{{ abc_environment_variable|
                       items2dict(key_name='abc_variable',
                                  value_name='abc_value') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/test_env.log 
HelloWorld
```

See ["Setting the remote environment"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html#setting-the-remote-environment).  Fit the parameters and escalation to your needs.

Comment: It works perfectly !! It was exactly what I needed ! Thank you very much :)